# Не работает функция PHP

Tags: php

Есть функция

```
function get_bank($bin) {
        $bin = str_replace(' ', '', $bin);
        $bin = substr($bin, 0, 6);
        $ch = curl_init("https://bincheck.io/bin/{$bin}");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        $bank = get_string_between($res, 'Bank</td>', '</td>');
        $bank = str_replace('<td>', '', $bank);
        $bank = str_replace('</td>', '', $bank);
        $bank = str_replace('<td style="text-align: left;" width="60%">', '', $bank);
        $bank = trim(str_replace("\n", '', $bank));
        if (empty($bank)) {
                $bank = get_string_between($res, '</h6><p>', '<br>');
        }
        $bank = strip_tags($bank);
        return $bank;
}
```

Работала на ура. Сегодня сломалось. Помогите как решить проблему.

Comment: Что значит сломалась? Как вы поняли что сломалось? Вижу что функция обращается ко внешнему URL (https://bincheck.io/), и раз уж вы говорите что ранее все работало, а сейчас вдруг перестало, не исключено что сломалось что-то как раз на том ресурсе к которому идет обращение. Или же что-то просто изменилось и вы теперь получаете другой ответ

Comment: Можете помочь решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 0):

не работает потому что сервис редиректит на другую страницу с результатом, нужно добавить опцию CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION со значением true к CURL запросу